# Use case of API Management + App Gateway for hosting internet facing API

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

We intended to host the internet facing API in azure app service.

We see the use of app gateway, the use case of WAF on top of the L7 load balancer

API Management use case is the one debatable, though it does provides a lot goodies,

- $$$$, can't afford the premium tier, so the use without vnet does not quite make a lot of sense in security view
- team also argues could use a sidecar container (e.g. dapr) to serve as an api manager, e.g. to parse the jwt

Thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access any external API which is hosted on any on-premise server, then you can consider this path : On-premise ----> s2s ( Site to Site) VPN ----> VNet ----> application in VNet.

You may follow : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/tutorial-site-to-site-portal
Please consider these links for the case:

https://medium.com/azure-architects/azure-api-management-and-application-gateway-integration-a31fde80f3db

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-integrate-internal-vnet-appgateway

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/apps/publish-internal-apis-externally

Comment: The use case is for inbound call

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [API Management self-hosted gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/self-hosted-gateway-overview) along with a
Dapr sidecar leveraging [API Management Dapr integration policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-dapr-policies). That way you wouldn't need the Premium Tier for VNet support.